# What is wrong with my Regex Function?

Tags: php, regex

It seems like such a simple matter. Anyways, at the bottom of my code is an array which uses the outcome of the function. Now it doesn't seem to be working and i think it might be my regex for scanning Meta Keywords. So basically, I want to know what my function is doing wrong or how to create a fully working regex code

```
function getKeywords($link) {
$str2 = file_get_contents($link);    
if (strlen($str2)>0) {
    preg_match_all( '(?i)<meta\\s+name=\"keywords\"\\s+content=\"(.*?)\">', $str2, $keywords);
  return $keywords[1];
}
}
```

Comment: About your regex, why not using something like that : `(<meta name="keywords" content=")(.*)("[/ ]{0,2}>)` ?

Comment: Your regex is going to fail as soon as you find a page where the meta tag looks like `<meta content="..." name="...">`.  Please consider using a proper DOM parser.  http://htmlparsing.com/ should get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
function getKeywords($link) {
    $str2 = file_get_contents($link);    
    if (strlen($str2)>0) {
        if(preg_match( '/<meta\s+name="keywords"\s+content="(.*?)">/i', $str2, $keywords))
            return $keywords[1];
        else
            return "";

    }
}
```

You had multiple problems with your expression:

1). To many escape chars for \s and \"

2). You didn't lead with a / and end with a /

3). You were using preg_match_all instead of preg_match

4). You didn't handle the case when no keyword meta tag can be found.

Comment: This assumes there is no space between the last `"` and `>`. Try this: `/<meta\s+name="keywords"\s+content="(.*?)"\s*>/i`